# Как сверстать расположение фото?

Tags: вёрстка, веб-программирование, позиционирование

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так надо, не пойму, как сверстать такое расположение картинок с учетом размеров сетки. Хотя бы расположить их согласно макету, размеры подгоню.

Comment: Использовать flexbox

Comment: + должна быть перспектива на адаптивность.

Comment: как будут задаваться размеры картинок?

Comment: картинки накладываются через background. То есть размеры задаются только <div> блокам

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Набросал верстку.

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.mini-width {
  min-width: 150px;
}
.mini-height {
  min-height: 150px;
}
.column {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.padding {
  padding: 6px;
}
.fs {
  flex: 1;
}
.pseudo-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container padding">

  <div class="flex column" style="height: 100%;">
    <div class="flex fs">
      <div class="flex fs column">
        <div class="flex mini-height">
          <div class="fs padding">
            <img class="pseudo-img" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex fs">
          <div class="mini-width padding">
            <img class="pseudo-img" />
          </div>
          <div class="fs padding">
            <img class="pseudo-img" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex column mini-width">
        <div class="fs padding">
          <img class="pseudo-img" />
        </div>
        <div class="flex mini-height">
          <div class="fs padding">
            <img class="pseudo-img" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex mini-height">
      <div class="mini-width padding">
        <img class="pseudo-img" />
      </div>
      <div class="fs padding">
        <img class="pseudo-img" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Исходник codepen](http://codepen.io/bustexz/pen/pEpNNv?editors=1100)

Comment: Спасибо большое, Василий. Сейчас попробую применить ваш код. Я начал читать про flexbox, и еще не разобрался.

Comment: я разбил вашу верстку на блоки с размерами, установив диапазон минимальной высоты и максимальной длинны. Далее блочно установив минимальный блок + полностью оставшееся пространство. `минимальный блок + оставшееся пространство` в каждом элементе повторяется, если присмотреться

Comment: Еще раз спасибо, чуть подправил код под себя, и все стало прекрасно)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй что-то вроде этого

```css
.border{
  border: 1px solid black;  
}
```

```html
<div style="height:300px;width:300px">
  <div style="height:200px">
    <div style="width:60%;height:100%;float:left">
      <div class="border" style="height:30%"></div>
      <div style="height:60%">
        <div style="float:left;height:100%;width:40%" class="border"></div>
        <div style="float:right;height:100%;width:40%" class="border"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:30%;height:100%;float:right">
      <div style="height:60%;width:100%" class="border"></div>
      <div style="height:30%;width:100%" class="border"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="height:100px">
    <div class="border" style="height:100%;float:left;width:30%;"></div>
    <div class="border" style="height:100%;float:right;width:60%"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Надеюсь ход моих мыслей понятен

Comment: сейчас бы блоки в 2016 флоатом верстать) Люди переучивайтесь на верные технологии, а не на костыли

Comment: наверно, я последней раз верстал в далеком 2012 )

Comment: а теперь давайте про адаптивность, как вы решите проблему с ней используя ваш подход)

Comment: Там код с процентами, а основной квадрат можно менять в css media screen

Comment: Всё упирается во второй блок (с башней), его не стандартное расположение. Меня всегда удивляли дизайнеры не задумавшиеся о том как это все верстать потом(

Comment: А если ты будешь background-size: cover; применять?