# Адаптивная сетка на flex

Tags: css, flexbox

Здравствуйте! Как сделать адаптивную сетку такого плана?
Не прибегая к фреймворкам
Пробовал большой блок на float - не то, что нужно
Возможно ли на флексах это реализовать? Что бы было адаптивно.
Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: похожее http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/574051/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE/574062#574062

Comment: @akrasnov87 спасибо, попробую

Comment: Маловато информации о вашей задаче. В чем именно ваша проблема? Что, по вашему, значит "чтоб было адаптивно"? Вы и мы должны понимать: как должны перестраиваться блоки; какие из них имеют фиксированную высоту, а какие будут "тянуться". Я вижу несколько вариантов верстки: 1. флоаты; 2. флексы; 3. колонки; <del>4. сетка</del>. Последний вариант - это "на вырост".

Comment: @tutankhamun Извиняюсь. Маленькие блоки фикс, большой блок резиновый. При ресайзе - большой блок остается в том же ряде, выталкивая маленькие. Когда не помещается в ширину экрана - ресайзится

Comment: @tutankhamun правильно сказал. Дополните вопрос, конкретизируйте - что должно тянуться, что должно жаться, что фиксед - и получите развёрнутый ответ в яблочко. А так - можно только пофлудить..

Answer (score 4):

Вот такой вариант, как например:

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.row-wrap {
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.bit-12 {
  width: 70%;
}

.bit-2 {
  width: 50%;
}

.bit-21 {
  width: 30%;  
}

.bit-1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.bit-1,
.bit-2 {
  height: 150px;  
}

.bit-3 {
  height: 310px;
}


/* Доп. стили для стилизации */
.wrap {
  background: #777;  
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

[class*="bit-"] {  
  padding: .25rem;
}

.bit-12,
.bit-21 {
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
}

.img {
  background: deepskyblue;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="row">
    
    <div class="bit-12 row row-wrap">
      <div class="bit-2">
        <div class="img"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="bit-2">
        <div class="img"></div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="bit-2">
        <div class="img"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="bit-2">
        <div class="img"></div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="bit-2">
        <div class="img"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="bit-2">
        <div class="img"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="bit-21">
      <div class="bit-3">
        <div class="img"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="bit-1">
        <div class="img"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделай на гридах (Grid.
так на много проще и быстрее.
https://tuhub.ru/posts/css-grid-complete-guide

Comment: во время ответил)

Comment: Пожалуйста, примите во внимание, в разделе справки: [Почему и как удаляются некоторые ответы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), кроме всего прочего, сказано: _являются всего лишь ссылкой на другой сайт_.
Это сообщение, пожалуйста, или поправте, или удалите.